# Problem accessing OnChange javascript event of Radio Button

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, radio-button

I'm running in to the same problem [this individual has](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t97682-radio-button-client-events.html).  Specifically, I'm trying to get a clientside `onchange` javascript event to fire for my Radio Button.  Unfortunately, the code gets rendered with the `onchange` located on a span surrounding the radio button instead of on the radio button itself.

I am using other javascript within the page to manipulate the radio buttons, so `onclick` doesn't fully satisfy my needs.

Additionally, the answer that was given to the user in the link above was "too bad, use an html check box".  For my application, this is sub-par as I need the radio button to raise the OnCheckedChange event serverside.

One solution path I was attempting to go down (using jQuery 1.1.3.1) was to set the change events myself:

```
jQuery("input:radio").change(new function() { 
  setParent(jQuery(this)); 
  showUndo(jQuery(this)); 
});
```

Which mirrors the `onclick` event (which is currently implemented and I'm trying to convert to the onchange ;) )

```
onclick="setParent(this); showUndo(this);"
```

This didn't work, though. :'(

Comment: Did you ever .trigger() your event?

Comment: Change the line `new function()` to just `function()`. You're calling the function immediately, passing the return value to `change()` (which will trigger `change`, not bind to it). Let us know if that fixes anything.

Comment: @JustLoren: does that mean `new` was the problem?

Comment: @crescentfresh: Sure was.  The sample given by Jan also lacks the new, and functions great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me as expected. The event fires if the radio is changed, and 'this' in the onchange event handler points to the radio button object.

```
    <div id="test">
        <input type="radio" name="something"/>
        <input type="radio" name="something"/>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(":radio").change(function() {
                alert(this.name + ' changed');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Does this solve your problem?